# Azure Automation access to VM vs DevOps Winrm Access

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine, azure-automation, winrm

We have a VM that prevents us from running File copy commands or powershell execution from DevOps(WindowsMachineFileCopy@2,PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3). As Winrm is disabled. But it allows azure automation to run scripts inside the VM. How is Azure automation different in accessing  the VM than Azure DevOps. Is it possible to use the same feature in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 0):

About Azure automation access to VM:

If you want to access Virtual Machines using Azure Automation Runbooks then you will need to use [Hybrid Runbook Workers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker). This is an agent installed on one of your servers and registered back with your Azure Automation Account. From here you can then execute your runbook on your Hybrid Runbook Worker.

By default, whenever an Azure VM is provisioned an endpoint is defined for allowing PowerShell access from remote clients, as shown below:

[image]

Runbook enables you to run a PowerShell command on an Azure VM from Azure Automation. [Connect-AzureVM](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Connect-to-an-Azure-85f0782c) runbook relied on the use of a credential to remotely access the Azure VM via WinRM PowerShell Remoting.

Here are some references you can refer to:

- [Accessing an azure vm through Powershell remote from Azure
  Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50449994/accessing-an-azure-vm-through-powershell-remote-from-azure-automation)
- [Azure Automation: Run tasks on Azure Virtual Machines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-automation-run-tasks-on-azure-virtual-machines-without-opening-ports/)

About Winrm access to VM:

- [Setting up WinRM access for Virtual Machines in Azure Resource
  Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/winrm)
- [Enabling Remote Powershell connection to Azure Virtual Machine](https://geekdudes.wordpress.com/2016/11/16/enabling-remote-powershell-connection-to-azure-virtual-machine/)

Essentially, Azure Automation also relies on using credentials to remotely access Azure VM through WinRM PowerShell Remoting.

Comment: Winrm is disabled and Azure automation still works. Your post says otherwise